# Not able to get Uri from the Created File

Tags: java, android, kotlin, uri

I am trying to compress an Image and get the URI of the compressed Image using the below code :

```
private fun compressImage(){
        if (imageUri.value != null) {
            val compressedImagePath = SiliCompressor.with(application)
                .compress(
                    imageUri.value.toString(),
                    File(application.cacheDir,"temp")
                )
            val compressedImage = File(compressedImagePath)
            val compressedImageUri = Uri.fromFile(compressedImage)
        } 
    }
```

There is no error in the logs, however, after debugging I found out that the app gets stuck at `val compressedImageUri = Uri.fromFile(compressedImage)` and doesn't run the further code. What am I doing wrong ?

Any help would be really appreciated !!

Comment: Tell the values of the paths you use and get.

Comment: Hello @blackapps, Thanks for replying. The value of compressedImagePath that I get after the image has been compressed : /data/user/0/com.example.bookally/cache/temp/IMG_20210102_081605.jpg

Comment: Nothing wrong with that path. Sorry, but i dont believe your app hangs at that last statement.

Comment: Thanks for looking into my problem @blackapps, I appreciate it. Have a good day !!